# How to receive query in node js

Tags: node.js

After authorization through spotify web api in node I redirect to another page with url: http://localhost:8888/homepage#access_token=....
so I want to take the access token on that page and fetch data but when I use req.query I receive an empty object. Is there something wrong? How can I get that access token?

```
request.post(authOptions, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const access_token = body.access_token;
      const refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

      const options = {
        url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` },
        json: true
      };

      request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(body);
      });

      res.redirect(
        "/homepage#" +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          })
      );
```

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index/welcome");
});

router.get("/homepage", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index/homepage");
  console.log(req.query);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the token via a fragment instead of query parameters, aren't you?

```
const url = require('url'); 
res.redirect(url.format({
   pathname:"/homepage",
   query: {
      "access_token": access_token,
      "refresh_token": refresh_token
    }
 }));
```

Working with fragments is for client side handling only, it should never reach the server.

Comment: It works, thanks)) but I don't understand, could you explain a bit?

Comment: Fragments are passed after `#` and are just meant to be used to pass content to the client application (e.g. a common way to pass an access token via a callback URL to your angular frontend). It won't be passed to the server in any way (like to your node application, or in this case the express framework). Query parameters on the other hand are attached via `?` and can be used in the backend.